# Why is it necessary to call rewind_posts() when using the loop more than once?

Tags: loop, query-posts

The [rewind_posts function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) is meant to be used when the loop is going to be called more than once in a page with the same query.

If I call the same loop a second time in the page the result is the same as calling the rewind_posts function just before.

**Why is it necessary?** Is rewind_posts not calling again the content in the database (cache it somehow) while using the second loop, without using rewind_posts, is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Global `rewind_posts`

```
File: wp-includes/query.php
784: /**
785:  * Rewind the loop posts.
786:  *
787:  * @since 1.5.0
788:  *
789:  * @global WP_Query $wp_query Global WP_Query instance.
790:  */
791: function rewind_posts() {
792:    global $wp_query;
793:    $wp_query->rewind_posts();
794: }
```

and `rewind_posts` from `WP_Query` class.

```
File: wp-includes/class-wp-query.php
3144:    * Rewind the posts and reset post index.
3145:    *
3146:    * @since 1.5.0
3147:    * @access public
3148:    */
3149:   public function rewind_posts() {
3150:       $this->current_post = -1;
3151:       if ( $this->post_count > 0 ) {
3152:           $this->post = $this->posts[0];
3153:       }
3154:   }
```

can help us understand we are actually in the context of `$wp_query` object when we are *rewinding* using the global `rewind_posts`.

---

The [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) pointer you set:

```
// main loop
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

// rewind
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>

// new loop
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

suggests that this has to do something with the `$the_post` method.

#### So, what is the nature of `the_post()`?

```
File: /class-wp-query.php
3095:   public function the_post() {
3096:       global $post;
3097:       $this->in_the_loop = true;
3098: 
3099:       if ( $this->current_post == -1 ) // loop has just started
3100:           /**
3101:            * Fires once the loop is started.
3102:            *
3103:            * @since 2.0.0
3104:            *
3105:            * @param WP_Query &$this The WP_Query instance (passed by reference).
3106:            */
3107:           do_action_ref_array( 'loop_start', array( &$this ) );
3108: 
3109:       $post = $this->next_post();
3110:       $this->setup_postdata( $post );
3111:   }
```

[image]

At least we can understand that there is a `global $post` object being set each time we iterate the `while` loop.

The key for understanding is the `next_post()` method.

```
File: wp-includes/class-wp-query.php
3068:   /**
3069:    * Set up the next post and iterate current post index.
3070:    *
3071:    * @since 1.5.0
3072:    * @access public
3073:    *
3074:    * @return WP_Post Next post.
3075:    */
3076:   public function next_post() {
3077: 
3078:       $this->current_post++;
3079: 
3080:       $this->post = $this->posts[$this->current_post];
3081:       return $this->post;
3082:   }
```

That method finally explains we increment the current post pointer:

```
$this->current_post++;
```

Note that in the expression above the whole variable `$this->current_post` will be incremented.

```
($this->current_post)++;
```

This is equivalent to:

```
$this->current_post = $this->current_post + 1;
```

for those that hate to admit the syntax `$this->current_post++;` is pretty cool to increment a variable.

---

To recap:

Since we called `the_post()` and increased the `$this->current_post` pointer we need now to set this pointer to -1, if we plan to loop again.

```
3149:   public function rewind_posts() {
3150:       $this->current_post = -1;
3151:       if ( $this->post_count > 0 ) {
3152:           $this->post = $this->posts[0];
3153:       }
3154:   }
```

Strange enought, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer :) I guess now my question would be why if I call the loop again without rewind_posts the current post is reseted..

Comment: @Alvaro, please accept the answer, this would be another question where you must provide the full details.

Comment: it was a rhetorical question, but I might open another one. Thank you :)